# How to detect property value onchange event of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var Settings = {  
    color: localStorage.color,  
    size : localStorage.size
};
```

I'd like to automatically save the new values to localStorage once they are changed, that means I'd like to do something like this:

```
Settings.onchange = function(p){  
    localStorage[p] = this[p];
};
```

Is it possible?

PS: only Chrome support needed.

Comment: Are you okay with writing a property for each one?

Comment: That's not possible (well you could use ES5 getters and setters I suppose). I suggest to incorporate data encapsulation and use a method to set the properties, such as `set(key, value)` and handle the synchronisation inside that function.

Comment: Javascript [setters and getters](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/) are your answer (but only for browsers that support them).

Comment: @minitech it's better not for I properly have other properties in the future

Comment: According to [http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html), getters and setters work in Chrome 5+.

Answer (score 3):

According to @RobG 's comment, I wrote this function, and it works!

```
function onPropertyChange(o, callback){
    for(var p in o){
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            var originalVal = o[p];
            Object.defineProperty(o, p, {
               get: function(){
                   return originalVal;
               },
               set: function(val){
                   callback.call(o, p, val);
                   return originalVal = val;
               }
            });
        }
    }
}  

// example:  

var Settings = {
    color: localStorage.color || "red",
    size : localStorage.size  || "12px"
};

onPropertyChange(Settings, function(p, val){
    localStorage[p] = val;
});
```

gist here: https://gist.github.com/1897209

Comment: This can monitory properties that are already set, what about having some callback when a new property is added to the `Settings`?